# ASP BOILERPLATE MVC - Menu Order

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

How do I change the Order of the MenuItem - currently it is sorted Alphabetically, I dont want it to be sorted

```
 ).AddItem(
                    new MenuItemDefinition(
                        PageNames.Users,
                        L("Users"),
                        url: "Users",
                        icon: "fas fa-users",
                        permissionDependency: new SimplePermissionDependency(PermissionNames.Users)
                    )
                ).AddItem(
                    new MenuItemDefinition(
                        PageNames.Roles,
                        L("Roles"),
                        url: "Roles",
                        icon: "fas fa-theater-masks",
                        permissionDependency: new SimplePermissionDependency(PermissionNames.Roles)
                         )
                ).
```

Answer (score 1):

After initialize in aspnetboilerplate NavigationProvider ,You can sort items by any properties and add sorted list to menu for exmaple

```
var itms = menu.Items.ToList();
        itms = itms.OrderBy(p=>p.BlahBlah).ToList();
        menu.Items.Clear();
        foreach (var t in itms)
        {
            menu.AddItem(t);
        }
```

and you can make it recursive for all level menus.

Comment: Where do I find the menu initialization ? I dont want it to sort, I need it to display as I add them in NavigationProvider

Comment: This is the default behavior. Menus are displayed in the same order as they were added to the navigationProvider.